# Motion of head during sneezing

Tags: momentum, everyday-life, biophysics

When we sneeze, our head moves forward.
However since the air from our mouth moves forward with a high velocity, shouldn't the head should recoil backwards (like a gun, to conserve the momentum) instead of moving forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The sneeze is moving at about 4.5 m/s](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64057/what-is-the-average-speed-of-human-sneeze/64062), and the total volume is likely less than a litre (typical human lung capacity is about 6 litres). So the total mass expelled will be less than one gram, and the momentum will be less than $p_{sneeze}=4.5\times 10^{-3}$ kg m/s.

An adult human head masses about 4.5 kg. By momentum conservation, $p_{sneeze}+p_{head}=0$, or $v_{head}=p_{sneeze}/m_{head}$. In this case, that is $v_{head}\approx 10^{-3}$ m/s. So the recoil is tiny, easily balanced by neck muscles.

Comment: but why it moves forward?

Comment: Probably because of some reflex - the effect is purely muscular.